# why margin-top not working in percentage?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying o give some margin to **form** from top in percentage (%).why it is not taking this property .I want to to give some margin to **form** from top.

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/byQLFlLh4a2qaIEZgfJH?p=preview

I am giving like that

```
.login-form {
  margin-top: 40%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto; }
```

It is not taking this  **margin-top: 40%;** why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this should be comment but after giving `margin:top` you are giving `margin:auto` which is overriding the last one. So better you should use `margin:top` after the `margin:auto` and Use `!important` in **only last case** as it's not good practise.

check here http://plnkr.co/edit/d6Xku9eFPP1L6anS6PVy?p=preview

Comment: O have one Question ..on which unit margin should be given in webdevelopment on % or in px

Comment: margin should be in px but it just depend on the condition where you are using it as % will be change according to screen size and depend on responsive cases but px is great if you want fix gap in every screen resolution.

Comment: Don't use important but rather use the shorthand: margin: 40% auto auto auto.

Comment: @NathanielFlick, i just advice for !important if he wants to use above margin:auto or even he can use after that then no need of !importance. BDW thanx for downvote.

Comment: Sorry about the downvote i tried to change it just now and it wouldn't let me (fat thumbs on my mobile phone!). I do believe advising !important should be a last resort and it's not at all needed in this case when the issue is obviously importance and all the attributes involved are in the one class. If you edit your answer I can change my downvote.

Comment: no problem mate. :) M here to help and to learn. Thanx for point but i think its not wrong if we are using !important as we are only using when its important :)

Answer (score 2):

Just move the `margin: auto` *above* the `margin-top: 40%` so that the latter overrides the part of the former it relates to:

```
.login-form {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 40%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: O have one Question ..on which unit margin should be given in webdevelopment on % or in px?

Comment: @user944513: It depends on what you need. If you need a margin of, say, 4px, use 4px. If you need a margin of 40%, use 40%. Or em or rem or...

Comment: could you please tell me which is better for webdevelopment

Comment: @user944513: There is no "better." It depends on what you need to do.

Comment: @user944513, according to me px will be better in case for margin-top(and yours) as it won't affect any other thing but agree with T. J. that depends on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
.login-form {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 40%;
  width: 50%; }
```

first put the auto than `margin-top:40%;`